# XML Conversion using XSLT under Biztalk

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I need to do XML transform under Biztalk using XSLT, but the problem is I am not familiar with it and having difficulty understanding it.

What I need is a XSLT script that can transform this SOURCE XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:usp_GetStudentListResponse xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/BizTalk">
   <ns0:StoredProcedureResultSet0>
      <ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList">
         <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
         <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-13T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
         <ns1:SectionId>1</ns1:SectionId> 
         <ns1:SectionName>Red</ns1:SectionName> 
         <ns1:StudentName>John Doe</ns1:StudentName> 
      </ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0>
      <ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList">
         <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
         <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-13T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
         <ns1:SectionId>1</ns1:SectionId> 
         <ns1:SectionName>Red</ns1:SectionName> 
         <ns1:StudentName>Jane Doe</ns1:StudentName> 
      </ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0>
      <ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList">
         <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
         <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-13T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
         <ns1:SectionId>1</ns1:SectionId> 
         <ns1:SectionName>Red</ns1:SectionName> 
         <ns1:StudentName>Lee Copper</ns1:StudentName> 
      </ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0>

      <ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList">
         <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
         <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-12T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
         <ns1:SectionId>2</ns1:SectionId> 
         <ns1:SectionName>Blue</ns1:SectionName> 
         <ns1:StudentName>Mary Steel</ns1:StudentName> 
      </ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0>
      <ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList">
         <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
         <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-12T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
         <ns1:SectionId>2</ns1:SectionId> 
         <ns1:SectionName>Blue</ns1:SectionName> 
         <ns1:StudentName>Steve Burry</ns1:StudentName> 
      </ns1:StoredProcedureResultSet0>
   </ns0:StoredProcedureResultSet0>
   <ns0:ReturnValue>5</ns0:ReturnValue>
</ns0:usp_GetStudentListResponse>
```

To this OUTPUT XML:

```
<ns0:StudentListSumEnv xmlns:ns0="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumEnv">  
   <ns1:StudentListSumData xmlns:ns1="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumData">
      <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
      <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-13T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
      <ns1:SectionId>1</ns1:SectionId> 
      <ns1:SectionName>Red</ns1:SectionName> 
      <ns1:TotalStudent>3</ns1:TotalStudent> 
   </ns1:StudentListSumData>
   <ns1:StudentListSumData xmlns:ns1="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumData">
      <ns1:Subject>Math</ns1:Subject> 
      <ns1:TestDate>2016-11-12T00:00:00.000-00:00</ns1:TestDate> 
      <ns1:SectionId>2</ns1:SectionId> 
      <ns1:SectionName>Blue</ns1:SectionName> 
      <ns1:TotalStudent>2</ns1:TotalStudent> 
   </ns1:StudentListSumData>
</ns0:StudentListSumEnv>
```

Conditions are:

- Should be group by ns1:Subject AND ns1:TestDate AND ns1:SectionId
- Should count total student under the group defined above (ns1:Subject AND ns1:TestDate AND ns1:SectionId)

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) What have you tried so far? We are not a code-writing service but help you with your code, but for that you must edit your question to actually show the xsl you have got so far.

Comment: With a simple Google dig, you have [here on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0dfd38ba-85e6-4729-96b6-54fdfddcd4e7/multiply-and-cumulative-sum-based-on-group-in-biztalk-map) a similar problem with XSLT explanation included.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for my question, after 2 hours digging my script, I finally solved my problem.

Here my XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 s2 s1" version="1.0" 
    xmlns:s1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList" 
    xmlns:s2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/BizTalk" 
    xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_DedOt_GetOffSignerCrewList">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="GroupByBatchCode" match="s2:usp_GetStudentListResponse/s2:StoredProcedureResultSet0/s1:StoredProcedureResultSet0" use="concat(s1:Subject, '-', s1:TestDate, '-', s1:SectionId)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <StudentListSumEnv xmlns:ns0="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumEnv">
      <xsl:for-each select="s2:usp_GetStudentListResponse/s2:StoredProcedureResultSet0/s1:StoredProcedureResultSet0[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('GroupByBatchCode',concat(s1:Subject, '-', s1:TestDate, '-', s1:SectionId)))]">
         <StudentListSumData xmlns:ns1="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumData">   
            <Subject>
               <xsl:value-of select="s1:Subject/text()" />
            </Subject>
            <TestDate>
               <xsl:value-of select="s1:TestDate/text()" />
            </TestDate>
            <SectionId>
               <xsl:value-of select="s1:SectionId/text()" />
            </SectionId>
            <SectionName>
               <xsl:value-of select="s1:SectionName/text()" />
            </SectionName>

            <TotalCount>
              <xsl:variable name="batchCodes" select="key('GroupByBatchCode',concat(s1:Subject, '-', s1:TestDate, '-', s1:SectionId))"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="count($batchCodes)"/>
            </TotalCount>

         </StudentListSumData>    
      </xsl:for-each> 
   </StudentListSumEnv>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That yield below results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentListSumEnv xmlns:ns0="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumEnv">
    <StudentListSumData xmlns:ns1="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumData">
        <Subject>Math</Subject>
        <TestDate>2016-11-13T00:00:00.000-00:00</TestDate>
        <SectionId>1</SectionId>
        <SectionName>Red</SectionName>
        <TotalCount>3</TotalCount>
    </StudentListSumData>
    <StudentListSumData xmlns:ns1="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumData">
        <Subject>Math</Subject>
        <TestDate>2016-11-12T00:00:00.000-00:00</TestDate>
        <SectionId>2</SectionId>
        <SectionName>Blue</SectionName>
        <TotalCount>2</TotalCount>
    </StudentListSumData>
</StudentListSumEnv>
```

Thanks for the wonderful online xslt site http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation as my script editor.

Here my complete scripts => http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.WCu4pDYkrg8

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
        xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" 
        exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 s2 s1" version="1.0" 
        xmlns:s1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_GetStudentList" 
        xmlns:s2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/BizTalk" 
        xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/BizTalk/usp_DedOt_GetOffSignerCrewList">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="GroupByBatchCode" match="s2:usp_GetStudentListResponse/s2:StoredProcedureResultSet0/s1:StoredProcedureResultSet0" use="concat(s1:Subject, '-', s1:TestDate, '-', s1:SectionId)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <ns0:StudentListSumEnv xmlns:ns0="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumEnv">
          <xsl:for-each select="s2:usp_GetStudentListResponse/s2:StoredProcedureResultSet0/s1:StoredProcedureResultSet0[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('GroupByBatchCode',concat(s1:Subject, '-', s1:TestDate, '-', s1:SectionId)))]">
             <ns1:StudentListSumData xmlns:ns1="http://School.Subject.Schema.StudentListSumData">   
                <ns1:Subject>
                   <xsl:value-of select="s1:Subject/text()" />
                </ns1:Subject>
                <ns1:TestDate>
                   <xsl:value-of select="s1:TestDate/text()" />
                </ns1:TestDate>
                <ns1:SectionId>
                   <xsl:value-of select="s1:SectionId/text()" />
                </ns1:SectionId>
                <ns1:SectionName>
                   <xsl:value-of select="s1:SectionName/text()" />
                </ns1:SectionName>
                <ns1:TotalStudent>
                  <xsl:variable name="batchCodes" select="key('GroupByBatchCode',concat(s1:Subject, '-', s1:TestDate, '-', s1:SectionId))"/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="count($batchCodes)"/>
                </ns1:TotalStudent>
             </ns1:StudentListSumData>    
          </xsl:for-each> 
       </ns0:StudentListSumEnv>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>*

*
```